# PostgreSQL transform value from jsonb column to other column

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database v10 with the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  custom_fields jsonb not null default '{}'::jsonb,
  guest_profile_id character varying(100)
);
INSERT INTO test (id, custom_fields) VALUES (1, '[{"protelSurname": "Smith", "servicio_tags": ["protel-info"], "protelUniqueID": "[{\"ID\":\"Test1-ID\",\"Type\":\"21\",\"ID_Context\":\"GHA\"}{\"ID\":\"4842148\",\"Type\":\"1\",\"ID_Context\":\"protelIO\"}]",    "protelGivenName": "Seth"}, {"value": "Test", "display_name": "Traces", "servicio_tags": ["trace"]}, {...}]');
INSERT INTO test (id, custom_fields) VALUES (2, '[{"protelSurname": "Smith", "servicio_tags": ["protel-info"], "protelUniqueID": "[{\"ID\":\"Test2-ID\",\"Type\":\"21\",\"ID_Context\":\"GHA\"},{\"ID\":\"4842148\",\"Type\":\"1\",\"ID_Context\":\"protelIO\"}]", "protelGivenName": "Seth"}, {"value": "Test2", "display_name": "Traces", "servicio_tags": ["trace"]}, {...}]');
INSERT INTO test (id, custom_fields) VALUES (3, '[{"value": "Test3-ID", "display_name": "Test", "servicio_tags": ["person-name"]}, {...}]');
INSERT INTO test (id, custom_fields) VALUES (4, '[{"value": "Test4-ID", "display_name": "Test", "servicio_tags": ["profile-id"]}, {...}]');
```

There are way more records in the real table.

**Goal:** I want to transfer the TestX-ID values into the column guest_profile_id in the same row. And only those values not the other JSONB objects or values etc.

**My try:**

```
do $$
declare
    colvar varchar;
begin
select x ->> 'ID' from (select jsonb_array_elements(f) from (
select (field ->>'protelUniqueID')::jsonb f
FROM guest_group gg,
lateral jsonb_array_elements(custom_fields) AS field
WHERE value @> '{"servicio_tags": ["protel-info"]}'::jsonb
) d(f)) dd(x) 
where x->>'ID_Context'='protelIO'
 into colvar;
    raise notice 'colvar: %', colvar;
end
$$;
execute format('UPDATE guest_group SET guest_profile_id = %s, colvar);
```

**My Result:** It only takes Test1-ID and stores it in all rows in the guest_profile_id column.

**My Problem:** I want to store each TestX-ID in the custom_fields column into the guest_profile_id column in the same row.

**My assumption:** I need to add a loop to this query. If the query up there does not find any value, the loop should try the next query: e.g.:

```
SELECT field ->>'value'
FROM guest_group gg
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(custom_fields) AS field
WHERE value @> '{"servicio_tags": ["profile-id"]}'::jsonb
```

And then the next:

```
SELECT field ->>'value'
FROM guest_group gg
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(custom_fields) AS field
WHERE value @> '{"servicio_tags": ["person-name"]}'::jsonb
```

When all TestX-ID values are copied into the guest_profile_id column in the same row, the goal is reached.

How can I put all this together? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: What is your problem (what's wrong with your attempt) / (your error message) / your question / your version of Postgres / your table definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to store each TestX-ID in the custom_fields column into the guest_profile_id column in the same row.

No need for PL/PGSQL, loops or dynamic sql. Just use a single query of the form

```
UPDATE guest_group
SET guest_profile_id = (/* complex expression */);
```

In your case, with that complex expression it amounts to

```
UPDATE guest_group
SET guest_profile_id = (
    SELECT x ->> 'ID'
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(custom_fields) AS field,
         jsonb_array_elements(field ->> 'protelUniqueID') AS dd(x)
    WHERE value @> '{"servicio_tags": ["protel-info"]}'::jsonb
      AND x->>'ID_Context' = 'protelIO'
);
```

> If the query up there does not find any value, it should try the next query

You can use the `COALESCE` function for that, or add some `OR` conditions to your query, or even use a `UNION`. Alternatively, add a `WHERE guest_profile_id IS NULL` to the update statement to exclude those rows that already have a value, and do multiple successive updates.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. Still I receive `ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression` - Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong here? Here the query: `UPDATE guest_group
SET guest_profile_id = 
  (SELECT field ->>'value'
FROM guest_group gg
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(custom_fields) AS field
WHERE value @> '{"servicio_tags": ["person-name"]}'::jsonb)`

Comment: It means that somehow the subquery returned more than one result for `guest_profile_id`, and of course that doesn't work in an `UPDATE` statement. You might need to restrict the `WHERE` conditions better, or add a `DISTINCT` clause if you're dealing with duplicates, or just add `LIMIT 1` if you don't care which of the options you get. For debugging, you could try something like `SELECT array(select subquery…) AS results, * FROM guest_group ORDER BY array_length(results) DESC` to find the rows where this happens and figure out why.

Comment: Thanks, it works with `LIMIT 1` for example but it stores in every row the same value. The same outcome like I had before with my try above.

Comment: @AntonHörl [it works just fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b22a60b62d1aea2ad7f42c861dcf03ad) with your example test data. You might want to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with the parts of the real data that are causing problems for you.

Comment: Oh, and make sure that your inner query does not have `FROM guest_group gg`, but is a subquery using the `customfields` from the outer (`UPDATE`) query.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help @Bergi!! That was really helpful. I still have trouble with chaining those queries with `COALESCE` but if I do not manage it I will ask a new question.